# The linker cant find blas and atlas on ubunu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, shared-library

i have installed blas and atlas by the following commands

sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev

sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev

But I am using a library which internally make use of it, while I am trying to make that library the following error appears

```
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the find command to locate these libraries. Use gcc option -L to specify this library's location. You may also need to set environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH